# Programming my ATmega8 board using Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmega, avrdude

I made a board with an ATmega8A (SMD-TQFP package). I installed the minicore library in the Arduino IDE. Now I'm able to flash the hex file using Atmel Studio 7 and able to read serial well.

But my problem is reading the digital pin status. It doesn't work well. I searched the internet and in the minicore library, I found that in the ATmega8, pin 14 (`PORT B.2`) is digital pin 10. So I wrote my code, however the pin does not change its status when toggling it.

Is it a mapping problem? If so, how can I map it?

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

int setbit = 0;//timer 2 isr
int setbit1 = 0;
int flag=0;
int flag1=0,k=0;
int flag2=0; int Light_CMD_J6=9;
int Button_Status_J6=10;

void setup() { 
    Timer1.initialize(100000); // set a timer of length 
    Timer1.attachInterrupt( timerIsr ); //  
    Serial.begin(19200);
    pinMode(Light_CMD_J6,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Button_Status_J6,INPUT);

}

void timerIsr()
{  
    setbit1=setbit1+1;
    if(setbit1==10)//2 seconds
    { 
        setbit1=0;
        flag2=1;
    }
}

void loop() {
    if(flag2==1)
    {
        Button_Status_J6=digitalRead(Button_Status_J6);
        Serial.print("BUTTON 6 STATE IS   =  ");
        Serial.println(Button_Status_J6);
        flag2=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't verified the mapping but I know that this line will cause you an issue:

```
Button_Status_J6=digitalRead(Button_Status_J6);
```

Here you are basically overwriting your mapping to digital pin 10, returning the result of the *digitalRead* into the variable *Button_Status_J6*, which will become either 0 or 1 on the first read.

At the top of your code, you would need to set-up another variable to read the result of the *digitalRead*:

```
int Button_Status_Read=0;
```

And then use it to read digital pin 10 (*Button_Status_J6*):

```
Button_Status_Read=digitalRead(Button_Status_J6);
Serial.print("BUTTON 6 STATE IS   =  ");
Serial.println(Button_Status_Read);
```

**EDIT**

The other issue was that the wrong clock source was selected for the fuse setting "SUT_CKSEL". When using an 8MHz external Crystal the following clock source needs to be selected:

> Ext Crystal/Resonator Medium Frequency

To start with, it is recommended to choose the option with the maximum start-up time ("16 CK + 64ms") to ensure the crystal oscillation has enough time to stabilize. After validation, faster start-up time can be selected.

Comment: May you are right, but still not working.

Comment: I edited it and editet the maping declaration  to: int button_state_J6=PORTB2;    but still give me random rading

Comment: @khoderakel Looks like mapping is correct. Could you share a schematic for your project? Have you exercised "Light_CMD_J6" to verify you can have control over GPIOs?

Comment: Yes you are right,No control over GPIO, only serial working fine.

Comment: Ha it's a good lead, did you have any other GPIOs you could try to control?

Comment: When I set GPIO pins HIGH or LOW it responses, but when I want to toggle a pin HIGH then LOW for example:
void loop()
{ 
Pin_state=HIGH;
delay(1000);
Pin_state=LOW;
}
It's remain HIGH(5v) all the time, and if I invert the toggle(the instruction order), I get LOW (GND) all the time too.
I use an osciloscope
I tried in codevision avr I get the same thing too.

Comment: @khoderakel I think you may have a problem with the MCU clocking and that the delay(1000) is much longer than it should be (although it is weird the serial is working fine, maybe it's on a different clock source). Are you using an external crystal? Have you selected the right clock source for your MCU?

Comment: Incorrect clock can affect GPIO output?!!.
When I started my project, I set the Baudrate to be 19200 but I Received the serial data correctly in baudrate 2400 in my PC,I searched in internet and tried to change the fuse setting till I Received in 19200 Baudrate using my pc.
Im using 8Mhz external crystal..
And Atmel studio to flash Hex file, in this link the setting I used:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LU-HsRUTCkGcHYH2Q1cCbDDo7KwF-0P3/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: No, it won't affect the GPIO output but it can affect the duration of the delay. You may think you are calling a delay of 1000 milliseconds but instead get a 5 min delay if the clock isn't set right. In the picture you've sent, the fuse setting shows you have selected the 8MHz "internal" RC and not you're external crystal. Have you tried changing the "SUT_CKSEL" setting to select your external crystal?

Comment: When I set this fuses value microcontroller locked..https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O16UzTNGywcnmFnar7QmF6dxtSbHcoHH/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I unlocked it by using R, C

Comment: @khoderakel In the last picture, it shows you have selected "Ext. RC Osc.", and you mentioned that you are using a Crystal as an external source (not an RC oscillator). I believe you need to select "Ext Crystal/Resonator Medium Frequency" instead. Choose the one with the maximum start-up time ("16 CK + 64ms") at first to ensure the crystal oscillation have enough time to stabilize and try again to run your sketch. Let me know if you get any luck :)

Comment: Now every think is ok, I'm very gratefull for your help and time @Cisco25

Comment: @khoderakel Great to hear! :) I have edited my original answer with the resolution for the fuse issue, I'd appreciate if you can mark it as "Answered" and why not a little up-vote ;)

Comment: I,m very sory I,m new here and dont have enough reputation, tomorrow I'll use my pc cause in my mobile no up-vote available.

Comment: @khoderakel I gave you 2 up-vote so now you can do the same with my answer :) Also take a look here on how-to mark your question as "Answered": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Thank you  @Cisco25 for your time and help..
The problem in GPIO control was, when I flash hex file using atmel studio I selected invalid clock, the right setting  is  "Ext Crystal/Resonator Medium Frequency with  start-up time ("16 CK + 64ms").